# I am writing a UI for an external program using Tkinter. How could I redirect any print statements to widget in tkinter? Almost like a live log

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, printing

This is the current UI script I have written...

```
import tkinter as ttk
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import os
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.ttk import *

app = ttk.Tk()

app.geometry("400x400")
app.configure(bg='gray')

photo = ttk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\ex\ex_button_active.png")
myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='normal')

ttk.Label(app, text='Ex', bg='gray', font=(
    'Verdana', 15)).pack(side=ttk.TOP, pady=10)
app.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\ex\ex_icon.ico')


def ex_activation():
    global pro
    print("Running program!")
    pro = subprocess.Popen("python programex.py", shell=True)


def ex_stop():
    global pro
    print("Stopping Program... Please Wait!")
    os.kill(pro.pid, 0)


ex_activation_button = ttk.Button(app, bg='black', image=photo, width=120, height=120, command=ex_activation)

ex_stop_button = ttk.Button(app, bg='Gray', text='Stop Program', width=12, command=ex_stop, height=3)

ex_stop_button['font'] = myFont

app.title("Ex")
ex_activation_button.pack(side=ttk.TOP)
ex_stop_button.pack(side=ttk.LEFT)

# app.mainloop()
while True:
    try:
        app.update()
        app.update_idletasks()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

The main goal is to take **ANY** print statements from the external script and have them printed to a tkinter widget line by line. I wanted to use the stdout method. [Here is a post I Had Found that May Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846193/how-to-redirecting-stdout-to-a-label-widget) Thank you in advance to anyone that can help me achieve this goal.

Comment: What's the problem with using `Label` to show it in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ttk.Label()` to show the last printed line on your GUI. You could try this:

```py
# Insert a label on your window
lab = ttk.Label(root, text="Some text")
lab.pack()

# Change the label text
def update_label(print_output):
    lab.configure(text=print_output)
```

If you prefer having all the lines, you could use a [textarea](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_text_widget.php) instead of a Label and append the lines instead of replace them.

To get the program output you could do it in multiple ways:

- Overload the python `print()` function, and add a line to call `update_label(text)`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550470/overload-print-python/550477#550477), but it's a little bit tricky.
- Replace all `print()` to `your_print()` so you can add the line above in a separate function, like this:

```py
# You will need to make sure to only give one argument, and it should be a string.
def your_print(text):
    update_label(text)
    print(text)
```

- The last one will come useful if you can't modify the other program, let's say it's already compiled. You could run the output of that program into a file (`SomeCommand > SomeFile.txt`), and then every second or so, your tkinter app could call `update_label()`. An example:

```py
## REPLACE root.mainloop() for this:

# These three lines are the equivalent of mainloop()
while True:
    root.update()
    root.update_idletasks()

    with open('somefile.txt') as filein:
        last_line = filein.read().split('\n')[-1]
        update_label(last_line)
```

Comment: Hi Eric Roy, I like the last of method of creating a text file as the file in for the program. Correct me if I'm wrong but in this answer, I could create a ttk label using the method above and then update that ttk label using a text file as a file in. Did i say this correctly?

Comment: Yes, this will work. Keep in mind that Labels were made to hold only one line, so if you plan having all of them you could use a textarea.

Comment: What would a textarea line look like? I would think it would be something like `app.textarea()` or whatever the root was defined as in the beginning...

Comment: Here you have a nice example, this will work for you. https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_text_widget.php